When building Qt 5.15 from source, single quotes in commands cause compilation errors
I'm trying to build Qt 5.15.5 on Windows 7 with MinGW-64. There were some small bugs during compiling but they were fixed without problems. Then at some moment the compilation started to fail with errors, I found that these errors are happening due to the commands in single quotes, for example:
'C:\Qt\5.15.5\build\qtbase\bin\moc.exe' -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DMINGW_HAS_SECURE_API=1 -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DQT_NO_LINKED_LIST -DQT_NO_JAVA_STYLE_ITERATORS -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_NO_FOREACH -DQFLOAT16_INCLUDE_FAST -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_BUILD_CORE_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS_SINCE=0x060000 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DPCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH=16 -DPCRE2_STATIC --include C:/Qt/5.15.5/build/qtbase/src/corelib/.moc/release/moc_predefs.h -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/win32-g++ -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/src/corelib -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/zlib/src -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/build/qtbase/src/corelib/global -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/md5 -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/md4 -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/sha3 -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/double-conversion/include -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz/src -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/src/3rdparty/tinycbor/src -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/src/corelib/.rcc/release -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/include -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/build/qtbase/include -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/build/qtbase/include/QtCore -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.15.5 -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.15.5/QtCore -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/build/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.15.5 -IC:/Qt/5.15.5/build/qtbase/include/QtCore/5.15.5/QtCore-IC:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/src/corelib/tmp -I. -IC:/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0 -IC:/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32 -IC:/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/backward -IC:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include -IC:/mingw64/include -IC:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include-fixed -IC:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --output-json C:/Qt/5.15.5/Src/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthreadpool.h -o .moc/release/moc_qthreadpool.cpp
    mingw32-make[4]: *** [Makefile.Release:9249: .moc/release/moc_qthread.cpp] Error -1073741511
    mingw32-make[4]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/5.15.5/build/qtbase/src/corelib'
    mingw32-make[3]: *** [Makefile:45: release] Error 2
    mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/5.15.5/build/qtbase/src/corelib'
    mingw32-make[2]: *** [Makefile:231: sub-corelib-make_first] Error 2
    mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/5.15.5/build/qtbase/src'
    mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile:54: sub-src-make_first] Error 2
    mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/5.15.5/build/qtbase'
    mingw32-make: *** [makefile:67: module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2

If I go to the current directory where the compiling takes place and execute the command without single quotes in 'C:\Qt\5.15.5\build\qtbase\bin\moc.exe', it is executing without problems, and when I return to the build directory and continue compiling, it is going on until the next error is happening.
How to fix this problem?

Your file path contains at least one '\b' character, which could be translated as a backspace character.  Try enclosing the path and filename between double quotes.

@ThomasMatthews Where to do that? This command is auto-generated.

Error code -1073741511 translates to 0xC0000139 is DLL not found. The quotes do not seem to be a reason of the build failure.

@3CxEZiVlQ this error code may be whatever it is, but the fact is that it is compiling fine without quotes.

I disagree. The error code is very important. I believe you need to figure out why it can't find a dll while building. This could be a PATH problem.

Are you building in some MinGW bash terminal or similar?

"If I go to the current directory" Which is the current directory? Make runs in C:/Qt/5.15.5/build/qtbase/src/corelib when gets the error.

What shell are you building in, cmd or msys2? qmake creates different makefiles depending on whether sh available in %path% or not

@3CxEZiVlQ My English is terrible, I meant that the building process says that it is changing the current directory to corelib, and I'm also "cd-ing" to this directory to compile it by hand.

@mugiseyebrows I'm building in a cmd shell.

You English is good, you just omitted technical details. If you run make in the cmd shell, it does not work. Run make in bash that should come with MSYS2.
